# In WPF, how do I bind changeable values from codebehind into animation in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, binding

The wanted state is like this:
There are notoverlaping containers (Borders) placed together on common canvas. When choosen Border is leftclicked, it is zoomed-in by animation and all other Borders are zoomed-out/moved at the same time. All Borders are fluently animated to new position/size from its last position/size.
When any Border is rightclicked, all Borders are animated (returned) to default place/size.
After the clicking on any Border, there is in codebehind defined different set of place/size values for each Border to finaly reach. Those new values are (should be) passed/binded to animation.

I am new in WPF and the state I have reached for this task is this:
Any first click in any Border right after the program starts will do the wanted animated place/size change. But any other followed clicks just repeats the first same again without CHANGING the values defined in codebehind after click event. More over, even this first FINAL positions/sizes are animated correctly, but the INITIAL values comes from "outthere"(behinscreen) like the animation is not reading the "ActualValues" from Borders.

I am not searching for better other solution using Wrappanel or using Styles. I am searching for solution how to pass dynamicaly changeable values from codebehind into XAML defined animation.

```
Imports System.Windows.Media.Animation

Public Class Window_NAS_HVZ

    Public Property Border1_Wid As Double
    Public Property Border1_Hgh As Double
    Public Property Border1_Top As Double
    Public Property Border1_Left As Double
    Public Property Border2_Wid As Double
    Public Property Border2_Hgh As Double
    Public Property Border2_Top As Double
    Public Property Border2_Left As Double
    Public Property Border3_Wid As Double
    Public Property Border3_Hgh As Double
    Public Property Border3_Top As Double
    Public Property Border3_Left As Double

    Public Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        DataContext = Me
    End Sub

    Public Sub Zoom_SIZE_default_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Border1_Wid = 400 : Border1_Hgh = 200 : Border1_Top = 20 : Border1_Left = 50
        Border2_Wid = 400 : Border2_Hgh = 200 : Border2_Top = 240 : Border2_Left = 50
        Border3_Wid = 400 : Border3_Hgh = 200 : Border3_Top = 460 : Border3_Left = 50
        BeginStoryboard(TryCast(FindResource("Borders_Resize"), Storyboard))
    End Sub

    Public Sub Zoom_SIZE_1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Border1_Wid = 400 : Border1_Hgh = 500 : Border1_Top = 20 : Border1_Left = 50
        Border2_Wid = 200 : Border2_Hgh = 50 : Border2_Top = 540 : Border2_Left = 150
        Border3_Wid = 200 : Border3_Hgh = 50 : Border3_Top = 610 : Border3_Left = 150
        BeginStoryboard(TryCast(FindResource("Borders_Resize"), Storyboard))
    End Sub

    Public Sub Zoom_SIZE_2_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Border1_Wid = 200 : Border1_Hgh = 50 : Border1_Top = 20 : Border1_Left = 150
        Border2_Wid = 400 : Border2_Hgh = 500 : Border2_Top = 90 : Border2_Left = 50
        Border3_Wid = 200 : Border3_Hgh = 50 : Border3_Top = 610 : Border3_Left = 150
        BeginStoryboard(TryCast(FindResource("Borders_Resize"), Storyboard))
    End Sub
    Public Sub Zoom_SIZE_3_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Border1_Wid = 200 : Border1_Hgh = 50 : Border1_Top = 20 : Border1_Left = 150
        Border2_Wid = 200 : Border2_Hgh = 50 : Border2_Top = 90 : Border2_Left = 150
        Border3_Wid = 400 : Border3_Hgh = 500 : Border3_Top = 160 : Border3_Left = 50
        BeginStoryboard(TryCast(FindResource("Borders_Resize"), Storyboard))
    End Sub

End Class
```

And this is its XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Window_NAS_HVZ"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Width="600" Height="800"  
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Borders_Resize">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BORDER_1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Height)" Duration="0:0:0.2" From="{Binding ActualHeight}" To="{Binding Path=Border1_Hgh}"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BORDER_2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Height)" Duration="0:0:0.2" From="{Binding ActualHeight}" To="{Binding Path=Border2_Hgh}"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BORDER_3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Height)" Duration="0:0:0.2" From="{Binding ActualHeight}" To="{Binding Path=Border3_Hgh}"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BORDER_1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Width)" Duration="0:0:0.2" From="{Binding ActualWidth}" To="{Binding Path=Border1_Wid}"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BORDER_2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Width)" Duration="0:0:0.2" From="{Binding ActualWidth}" To="{Binding Path=Border2_Wid}"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BORDER_3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Width)" Duration="0:0:0.2" From="{Binding ActualWidth}" To="{Binding Path=Border3_Wid}"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BORDER_1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" Duration="0:0:0.2" From="{Binding Actual.Canvas.Top}" To="{Binding Path=Border1_Top}"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BORDER_2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" Duration="0:0:0.2" From="{Binding Actual.Canvas.Top}" To="{Binding Path=Border2_Top}"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BORDER_3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" Duration="0:0:0.2" From="{Binding Actual.Canvas.Top}" To="{Binding Path=Border3_Top}"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BORDER_1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Duration="0:0:0.2" From="{Binding Actual.Canvas.Left}" To="{Binding Path=Border1_Left}"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BORDER_2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Duration="0:0:0.2" From="{Binding Actual.Canvas.Left}" To="{Binding Path=Border2_Left}"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BORDER_3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Duration="0:0:0.2" From="{Binding Actual.Canvas.Left}" To="{Binding Path=Border3_Left}"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
  
    <Grid >
        <Viewbox >
            <Canvas  Background="White" Width="500" Height="680">
                <Border  x:Name="BORDER_1" Width="400"  Height="200" Background="Green"  Canvas.Left="50"  Canvas.Top="20" 
                         MouseLeftButtonDown ="Zoom_SIZE_1_Click"
                         MouseRightButtonDown ="Zoom_SIZE_default_Click"
                         Opacity="0.5">
                </Border>

                <Border  x:Name="BORDER_2" Background="Red" Width="400"  Height="200"  Canvas.Left="50"  Canvas.Top="240"
                         MouseLeftButtonDown ="Zoom_SIZE_2_Click"
                         MouseRightButtonDown ="Zoom_SIZE_default_Click"
                         Opacity="0.5">
                </Border>

                <Border  x:Name="BORDER_3" Background="Blue"  Width="400"  Height="200"  Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="460"
                         MouseLeftButtonDown ="Zoom_SIZE_3_Click"
                         MouseRightButtonDown ="Zoom_SIZE_default_Click"
                         Opacity="0.5" >
                </Border>
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is a picture of wanted state:

http://www.z7h.sk/resizedborders.jpg

1 - default position (after rightclick)
2 - after leftclick on the top Border
3 - after leftclick on the mid Border
4 - after leftclick on the low Border

Comment: Searching for how and where to Implement INotifyPropertyChanged helped me.
Now, accordingly to which Border is clicked, the different values are read and FINAL animation places/sizes are correct.
But still, the INITIAL values of place/size of Borders in the animation (...From="{Binding ActualWidth}...") are "ignored". Animation still starts from values "out of screen".
How to handle that?

Comment: Changing  ...From="{Binding ActualHeight}...   to   ...From="{Binding Actual.BORDER_1.Height}..."  will do the needed magic.